# Setting the confidence interval in acf plots

Tags: r, time-series

I plotted the ***autocorrelation function*** of a given set of residuals I obtained from estimating a linear regression model:

```
> require("stats")
> acf(Reg$residuals)
```

It resulted in the following graphic:

[image: acf plot]

I then wanted to look up what kind of confidence interval (95%, 99%) is displayed, but there is no information on that within the help section of the function. In addition to that I could not find a way to adjust the confidence interval manually.

Is there a way to manually set the confidence interval displayed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See `?plot.acf`:

> plot(x, ci = 0.95, ...)

and:

> **ci**: coverage probability for confidence interval. Plotting of the confidence interval is suppressed if ci is zero or negative.

That is, the default is 95% confidence intervals, and e.g.:

```
plot(acf(Reg$residuals), ci = 0.99)
```

should plot the 99% confidence intervals.